# How to send cookie in Request header in office JS task pane app? (Office-js Add-in with angular 4)

Tags: angular, office-js, office-addins, httpcookie, angular4-httpclient

Sending cookie in request header  (Office-js Add-in with angular 4)

```html
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('App-Url', this._apiConfigService.getApiCallBackUrl());
        headers.append('Authorization-Code', authCode);
        // created cookie.
        this._localStorageCookie.createCookie("state", state, null);
       return this.http.get(url, {
            headers: headers,
            body: '',
            withCredentials: true            

        }).map(this.fetchResposne).catch((initialError) => {});
```

I have log-in in form from office js dialog and then want to send cookie after successfully logedin.

When it hit to the Web-API,I am not able to get request cookie which i set.
I also tried request option "withCredentials" but not able to get success in that.

Appreciate early help! 
Happy Coding! 
Thanks.